# Push user to a logged in view not working

Tags: swiftui, ios16, swiftui-navigationstack

For iOS16+, I am using Google Sign In button on ContentView to authenticate users. If users are not authenticated, the button shows and user can go through the authentication process. Once authenticated, user is brought back to ContentView that also checks if user has been signed in. If so, we send the user to main app, say UserProfileView.

My code is as follows. When the user is signed in, UserProfileView renders inside ContentView rather than sending the user new a completely new view. I've tried various ways but can't figure out how to do so.

```
import SwiftUI
import GoogleSignIn
import GoogleSignInSwift

struct ContentView: View {
    //some vars declared
    @State private var path = NavigationPath()
    @EnvironmentObject var authViewModel: AuthenticationViewModel
    @ObservedObject var vm = GoogleSignInButtonViewModel(style: .wide)

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        //some code with logo etc
        HStack {
            switch authViewModel.state {
            case .signedIn:
                let _ = print("User is signed in")
                NavigationStack(path: $path) {
                    Text("")
                }
                .onAppear {
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                        path.append("UserProfileView")
                    }
                }
            case .signedOut:
                let _ = print("User is signed out")
                GoogleSignInButton(viewModel: vm, action: authViewModel.signIn)
                    .accessibilityIdentifier("GoogleSignInButton")
                    .accessibility(hint: Text("Sign in with Google button."))
                    .padding()
            }
        }
    }
    .padding()
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    .background(Color("Standard").ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .all))
}
```

ContentView before user signs in:

[image: View before user signs in]

ContentView after user signs in; note the UserProfileView renders inside the ContentView (where the Google Sign In button used to be), rather than navigating to a UserProfileView that takes up the entire screen.

[image: View after user signs in; note the UserProfileView renders inside the ContentView, rather than navigating to a UserProfileView that takes up the entire screen.]

UserProfileView - user should be directed from ContentView to here upon login. UserProfileView as shown below takes up the whole screen, which is what I want.

[image: UserProfileView - user should be directed from ContentView to here upon login.]

Would appreciate some help here.

Comment: You should provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - this is a SwiftUI question, not an authentication problem. Is `AuthenticationViewModel.state` a `@Published` variable?

Comment: @HunterLion yes it is

Comment: Assuming the problem isn't with the Google code, please remove that and make a [mcve] to confirm that is the case

Comment: . What _exactly_ to you want to happen? What does _"sending the user new a completely new view"_ mean in this case?

Comment: @AshleyMills I've updated the question with some screenshots. There is no problem with the Google code as it works as intended. It is merely about "pushing" the user to the UserProfileView which I can't seem to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for the screenshots. If the Google code isn't a problem, please remove it so others can easily  recreate your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this, just using a `SignInState` enum to switch between views:

```
enum SignInState {
    case signedIn, signedOut
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var state: SignInState
        
    var body: some View {
        switch state {
        case .signedOut:
            SignInView(state: $state)
        case .signedIn:
            NavigationStack {
                UserProfileView()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SignInView: View {
    
    @Binding var state: SignInState
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Rectangle()
                .frame(width: 300, height: 400)
                
            Button("Sign in") {
                state = .signedIn
            }
            .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
            .padding()
            Spacer()
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .background(.mint, ignoresSafeAreaEdges: .all)
        .navigationTitle("Sign in")
    }
}

struct UserProfileView: View {    
    var body: some View {
        Text("User Profile")
            .navigationTitle("User Profile")
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: The trick was to move NavigationStack containing the UserProfileView() outside of the top-level VStack!